# how can tensorflow propogate the loss into split weight

Tags: tensorflow

I recently have a NLP task of text classification and I use a LSTM to generate a representation of the inputs and then get it through a linear layer. The pseudo-code is like this:

```py
final_state = tf.nn.LSTM(....)
logits = tf.softmax(final_state * W + b)
```

and the weight matrix above I used the function of:

```py
W = tf.get_variable('w', shape = [size, class_vocab], dtype = tf.float32)
```

and until now the loss function is cross-entropy, that's something like this:

```py
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy(logits,true_labels)
```

It works.

But now the thing is that I have to take an orthogonality constraint on my weight matrix when I calculates the loss, and here is my code:

```py
first_value, rest_value = tf.split(W, [1, length - 1], axis = 1)
rest_value = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(rest_value, axis = 1), axis = 1)
orthogonality_matrix = tf.matmul(first_value, rest_value, transpose_b = True)
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy(logits,true_labels) + tf.nn.l2_norm(orthogonality_matrix)
```

I want the first column of the weight matrix stay far away from the rest vectors because the class which the first column stands for is totally different from the others.

But it doesn't work since each time the update operation executed, the weight matrix changed and it changed in the same way regardless of whether I take the orthogonality constraints. (To demonstrate it I initialize W with all zeros.)

I doubt that when I split the W matrix I only copy the value from in into a constant tensor and thus when I use these tensors to calculate the loss it can't train the original W.

So what should I do to take the orthogonality constraint into consideration?

Or maybe I should multiple the final_state and the weight vectors for different classes separately instead of an integral weight matrix?? But it looks trivial :(

Comment: That's a fine way to add an orthogonality regularizer. Maybe the update is the same because W is zero and so the value of the regularizer is zero (and so the gradient is unaffected)?

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thank you! Yes I print the loss respectively and find out that the loss of orthogonality is too small compared to the softmax loss..And it indeed  can propagate the loss to the split weight matrix in tensorflow. Thanks again!